# Is markdown supported in jobs messages?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

When messaging back an forth on a job thread via [job messages](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages?userId=me) it's not clear if it supports markdown.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Almost certainly not; the editor is just a plain text box and none of the messages I’ve received have any markup. If Markdown was supported, I’d expect a rich editor and preview, at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that [Martijn Pieters is right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371118/is-markdown-supported-in-jobs-messages#comment610244_371118). Job messages don't support markdown at this time.